# ElasticSearch - Searching for exact text match without keeping two copies in index?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, full-text-search

Exact matching for text is supported in ElasticSearch if the field mapping contains `"index" : "not_analyzed"`. That way, the field wont' be tokenized and ES will use the whole string for exact matching. [The Documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_exact_values.html)

Is there a way to support both full text searching and exact matching without having to create two fields: one for full-text, and one with `not_analyzed` mapping for exact matching?

An example use case:

We want to search by book titles.

- `I like trees` should return results of full text search
- `exact="I like trees"` should return only books that have the exact title `I like trees` and nothing else. Case insensitive is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `term` filter to do exact match searches

the filter looks like this

```
{
   "term" {
       "key" : "value"
   }
}
```

a query would look like this:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "term" : { 
                    "key" : "value"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that should work only if the mapping is set to `not_analyzed`, but that would mean I have to create two fields? One for full-text and one not? I'm asking if there's a way to avoid doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the data in two different fields, what you want is an ES multi-field.

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_multi_fields.html#_multi_fields